Does the MOSFET go into the linear region when the op-amp goes into saturation?
Consider the following two stage differential amplifier:

Let's say the input differential voltage is high enough to put the amplifier into saturation region. In that case MOSFET M6 will be pushed to its limits, and the simulation also shows that M6 goes into the linear region.
I want to know if this is the normal behaviour or if as a circuit designer I am supposed to still keep all the MOSFETs in the saturation region by somehow limiting the input differential voltage by some kind of feedback circuit.
NOTE: This is supposed to be an error amplifier for a DC power supply.  The output of this amplifier will control the duty cycle of the supply.

0
Are you designing an "op-amp" as a chip, or using discretes? Are the 100k resistors part of the "op-amp", or part of the external circuit that uses the op-amp?

This will be opamp as a chip. The 100k resistors in the diagram were supposed to be in the chip. I know they are a problem and will introduce supply noise in the input and the overall design is also not great but will be resolved in the later iterations.


as a circuit designer I am supposed to still keep all the mosfet in saturation region by somehow limiting the input differential voltage by some kind of feedback circuit?

Short answer: yes, but the feedback components should be external to the IC, to give the user of the IC maximum flexibility.
In the comments you stated that:

You are designing an "op-amp" as a chip, not with discretes.
The 100k resistors are part of the "op-amp" in the chip.

I suggest removing the 100k resistors from the chip, and letting the user of the chip install these if required.  This will both improve the circuit, and reduce the size of the IC (resistors can use significant space on an IC).
2024-08-12 UPDATE:
Appendix: Definition of I-V Operating Regions for MOSFET.

Link for above image:
https://eepower.com/technical-articles/understanding-linear-mosfets-and-their-applications/#

Thanks for your insightful answer. Just had one doubt, even if we use an amplifier as a comparator to let's say generate a PWM signal, do all the MOSFETs still need to be in saturation? I just want to know if there is any case where it's considered okay for a MOSFET in an amplifier to be in linear region.

Your question ** do all the MOSFETs still need to be in saturation?** Short answer: no, provided that the time required to change MOSFET from non-saturation to saturation is sufficiently fast for the application.   It takes time to charge/discharge the various capacitances of a MOSFET to change between the three different operating regions of the output I vs V curves.
Note: I have added an image to my answer to define the various regions of operation.

\$100k\Omega\$ can be easily implemented in an IC with polycrystalline silicon resistors (AKA poly resistors). They have high resistivity, so I'm not surprised they are inside your design.
On the other hand, why you'd make a resistive divider with them and refer them to the supply is another matter. I'd at least suggest to refer them to ground, I presume that's a bit cleaner than supply.
With regards to M6 going into linear with a high enough input drive... that is something your specifications must dictate. Obviously, no amplifier can handle arbitrary amplitudes at the input; there must always be a limit dictated by specs, and your job is to limit bigger amplitudes with other measures.
What kind of amplitude are you using in order to drive M6 into its linear region? How does that amplitude compare to what your system expects? How do you know your error amplifier is good enough to handle amplitudes at the input?
Also, your input stage seems rather small. I don't know if you have noise requirements, but I'd actually boost the gm of your system to reduce the input error signal. To that end, I'd make that W/L ratio at least 10x, or even more, like 50x.
EDIT: do all transistors need to be in saturation at all times?
Short answer is yes, but it depends.
First, all transistor must do what they are intended to do. Perhaps there's one transistor that is meant to work as a voltage controlled resistor, then that one doesn't need to be in saturation, obviously.
In your design, all transistors are meant to work in saturation region. However, the transition between saturation and an off state is smooth, you have weak and moredate inversion in between. In weak inversion, the Vgs can be smaller than the Vt, and then you get an exponential Ids=f(Vgs) kind of behavior. For instance, input stages can be biased in moderate inversion, while current sources need strong inversion for matching purposes.
If at some point in a transient simulation one of these transistor go off saturation, it is up to you judge whether this is good enough or not. It is impossible to make statements in a vacuum. Maybe they are actually going into weak inversion and it doesn't affect your circuit performance.
You need find a good way to judge whether that's ok or not, and usually this criteria can be derived from a set of specifications.

resistor divider using 100k were used to get (5+VIN_N)/2 at gate of M1 to get a dc biasing voltage of 2.5V. With just VIN_N, it's not possible to keep all mosfet in saturation as there is a minimum voltage that I must apply at gate of M1 to keep them in saturation and VIN_N can go to 0 or very low voltages. The circuit I showed keeps all mosfets in saturation but the 100k resistor connected between Gate and supply introduces supply noise to the input of the amplifier which is not at all desired. That's why I asked if it's okay for some mosfet to be in linear region for some region of operation

Indeed, any single-supply circuit needs a common-mode voltage to work properly. In a typical op-amp where good linearity is required, transistors going into triode region usually translates into poor distortion figures and everyone designs them such that they happen beyond the the highest input signal expected.
